# How to access the APIv3 from wordpress plugin files

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, api

I'm developing a little wordpress plugin which creates a custom post type with a custom field where I **would like to store an ID of one of the active contribution page of CiviCRM** in order to associate this content with the contribution page information.

This very same code works in theme files but fails when is used in plugin files, breaking the site.

```
   function get_contribution_info($f_type){
   $params = array(
       'version'    =>  3,
        'financial_type_id' => $f_type,
        'is_active' => '1'
    );
    try{
       $result = civicrm_api3('contribution_page', 'get', $params);
    } catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
        // handle error here
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
        $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
        return array('error' => $errorMessage, 'error_code' => $errorCode, 'error_data' => $errorData);
    }
    return $result[values];
    }

    $get_contrib = get_contribution_data( '1' );
    $contributions = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($get_contrib as $c) {
        $contributions[$i]['label'] = $c['title'];
        $contributions[$i]['value'] = $c['id'];
        $i++;
    }
```

I've tried to add a `require_once` the `class.api.php` without positive results.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Try prefixing your API call with:

```
civicrm_initialize();
```

The "class.api.php" is for when you want to use the REST API from an external site.

Comment: class.api.php works as well locally, but it does implement a class that is a wrapper around civicrm_api3, not that function, so doesn't solve your problem indeed.

Comment: @bgm Not seems to work in the plugin files. I added `civicrm_initialize();` inside the `try {}` just over the api call and still brakes the site. But works well in themes files...

Answer (score 2):

Solved!!!

```
   function get_contribution_info($f_type){

   $params = array(
       'version'    =>  3,
       'financial_type_id' => $f_type,
       'is_active' => '1'
   );
   try{
       if ( ! function_exists( 'civicrm_initialize' ) ) { return; }
       civicrm_initialize();
       $result = civicrm_api3('contribution_page', 'get', $params);
   } catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
       // handle error here
       $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
       $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
       $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
       return array('error' => $errorMessage, 'error_code' => $errorCode, 'error_data' => $errorData);
    }
   return $result[values];
}
```

**The key was on adding `civicrm_initialize();`**. Thanks to *@bgm* for the advice!